# Don't pass block when calling super

Tags: ruby

How can I set a block to nil for the `super` call?

```
class A
  def foo
    if block_given?
      result = yield 
      # do stuff with the yield result
    end
    # some more code
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    block_result = yield
    # process block results and store it
    # ...
    super
  end
end

B.new.foo { puts "block called" }
# => block called
# => block called
```

I don't want to yield the block twice. Is it somehow possible that `block_given?` in class `A`  returns false?

Background is that I don't own the `A` class and I can't change it's `foo` method but I want to avoid calling my block twice. I also don't want to pass a dummy / empty block to super, because the behaviour of `A`'s `foo` method changes when a block is given.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's actually not that obvious. From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance) we know that:

- calling `super` passes all arguments
- calling `super()` passes no arguments

What the documentation doesn't say is that this only applies to positional and keyword arguments. `super()` still passes a given block!

You have to explicitly unset the block by calling:

```
super(&nil)
```

#### How does this work?

You probably know that you can define a method with an explicit [block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument):

```
def foo(&block)
  # ...
end
```

and that you can pass it as a block to another method: (that other method might be `super`)

```
def foo(&block)
  super(&block)
end
```

Now, if you pass a block when calling the method, the corresponding `block` variable will be an instance of `Proc`:

```
def foo(&block)
  p block_given: block_given?, block: block
end

foo {}
#=> {:block_given=>true, :block=>#<Proc:0x00007ff4990d0030>}
```

If you call it without passing block, the `block` variable will just be `nil`:

```
foo
#=> {:block_given=>false, :block=>nil}
```

So if no block is given, `block` is `nil` and

```
super(&block)
```

becomes:

```
super(&nil)
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for!