# How to prevent `super` from yielding

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Duck` with an `initialize` method that yields to a block:

```
class Duck
  def initialize()
    if block_given?
      yield(self)
    end
  end
end
```

and a class `TalkingDuck` that greets the programmer when it is initialized.

```
class TalkingDuck < Duck
  def initialize()
    super()
    puts 'I am a duck'
  end
end
```

When I call the constructor `TalkingDuck.new` with a block, I don't want this block to be executed. This:

```
TalkingDuck.new { puts 'Quack' }
```

should only print `I am a duck`, but not `Quack`. How can I prevent the block from being executed?

Comment: See @Stefan’s great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279119/dont-pass-block-when-calling-super?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 9):

Ruby implicitly passes the arguments and the block of the current method to `super`. With arguments, that can be avoided by explicitly calling `super` with no arguments (`super()`). The same thing can be done with blocks. A block can be passed to a method with `&`:

```
greet = proc { puts 'hi' }
do_some_stuff(&greet)
```

you can explicitly avoid passing a block with `&nil`. In this case, this means you can change the `initialize` method of `TalkingDuck` to:

```
def initialize()
  super(&nil)
  puts 'I am a duck'
end
```

and it will explicitly discard any given block and not pass it further up to `super`, but you can still handle the block yourself inside the method.

Comment: Note: I found this information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670794/what-does-supernil-do-in-ruby) stackoverflow question, but since that question was `what does X do?`, nobody looking for `how do I do Y?` would likely find it. Alternative / better answers are, of course, still very much welcome :)

Comment: If your method takes any arguments, then passing `&nil` to prevent passing a block up prevents the default "pass all the arguments when you call `super` with no arguments", so you'll need to enumerate the arguments you want to pass up: `super arg1, arg2,...,&nil`

Comment: _"calling super with nil"_, i.e. `super(nil)` passes a single argument `nil` to super. You have to call `super()` in order to pass no arguments. That's quite a difference.